# Summarizing array of existing items and amounts from a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to speed up work in my catering company. I have an excel file with all the ingredients of all products.

For example:

[image: 0]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-AFHpl8aoIiMXz2RE1Xv7JcI7pCIMQfMoq-lQJBx5Gw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(master!E3:Z<>"", master!A3:A&"♦"&master!B3:B&"♦"&master!E1:1&"♦"&master!E3:Z&"♠", ))
 , , 500000)), , 500000)), "♠")), "♦")))
```

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({C2:C,VALUE(D2:D)},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1<>''
  group by Col1 
  order by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)'Total',Col1'Shopping List'"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

The following formula would work for one recipe:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER({E1:K1;QUERY(A1:K5,"SELECT E,F,G,H,I,J,K WHERE A='"&H25&"'", FALSE)}, NOT(ISBLANK(QUERY(A1:K5,"SELECT E,F,G,H,I,J,K WHERE A='"&H25&"'", FALSE)))))
```

(I put this as an example into cell I25).